# Unable to delete a tenant which I have created due to a change in MFA settings

Tags: azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

When I try to switch to that tenant or delete it, I first insert my username and password, then I'm prompted "Please digit the number that appears on your authenticator app" but NO CODE appears. Still, I am able to access all the other company services associated with that account and I do it through Notification sign-in option of Microsoft Authenticator app.
I suppose that to that directory is still associated with a MFA authentication method that I no longer use but I can't even change it because I can't access that directory....

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it is reaching out to the Authenticator app on an old device. If you switched to a new phone and still have the old device, you can [back up and recover account credentials in the Authenticator app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/back-up-and-recover-account-credentials-in-the-authenticator-app-bb939936-7a8d-4e88-bc43-49bc1a700a40).

The recommendation is to always keep break-glass admin account, by excluding one or more global admins so that you can revert the settings. If there is another global admin on the tenant, that global admin can set up one-time bypass for your account so that you will be able to login again.

They can do this by going to Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory > Security > Multi-Factor Authentication > One-time bypass .

Then you will be able to login to https://aka.ms/mfasetup using your username and password and change the MFA method.

However, if you are the only global admin on the tenant and do not have a breakglass account, the only option is to [open a support ticket](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/overview) with the Microsoft Data Protection team.

You can also call them, though it can take a while to get through on the phone: 866-807-5850